# page preview not showing on display template

Tags: search-results, display-template

I have created a display template which is a hover panel. I am wanting to add the page preview thing but at the moment it is not working. I added from a default display template that works but for some reason it just shows a blank box.
Here is my code:

```
 <html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
    <head>
    <title>News Article Hover Panel</title>

    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    <mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
    <mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Displays a result hover panel tailored for a web page.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
    <mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
    <mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchHoverPanel;#</mso:TargetControlType>
    <mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
    <mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'Title','Path':'Path','PublishingPageContentOWSHTML':'PublishingPageContentOWSHTML','EditorOWSUSER':'EditorOWSUSER','LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime','CollapsingStatus':'CollapsingStatus','DocId':'DocId','HitHighlightedSummary':'HitHighlightedSummary','HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties','FileExtension':'FileExtension','ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime','ParentLink':'ParentLink','FileType':'FileType','IsContainer':'IsContainer','SecondaryFileExtension':'SecondaryFileExtension','DisplayAuthor':'DisplayAuthor'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
    <mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/NBSNewsArticle_HoverPanel.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
    <mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
    </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    </xml><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Item_WebPage_HoverPanel">
    <!--#_
            var i = 0;
            var id = ctx.CurrentItem.csr_id;
            var loadSiteFrame = false;
            ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowFollowLink = true;
            ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowViewLibrary = false;
            ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowLastModifiedTime = false;
            ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ShowAuthors = false;

            var line1 = $getItemValue(ctx, "PublishingPageContentOWSHTML");
            if(line1.toString().length > 500)
            {
                line1 = line1.toString().substring(0,500)+"...";
            }


    _#-->
            <div class="ms-srch-hover-innerContainer ms-srch-hover-standardSize" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.inner) =#_">
                <div class="ms-srch-hover-arrowBorder" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.arrowBorder) =#_"></div>
                <div class="ms-srch-hover-arrow" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.arrow) =#_"></div>
                <div class="ms-srch-hover-content" id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.content) =#_" data-displaytemplate="WebPageHoverPanel">
                    <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.header) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-header">
                        _#= ctx.RenderHeader(ctx) =#_
                    </div>
                    <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.body) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-body">
    <!--#_
                        if(true) {
                           // ctx.CurrentItem.csr_DataShown = true;
                            //loadSiteFrame = true;
                            var idViewerEncoded = $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.viewer);
                            var idGlassViewerEncoded = "glass_" + idViewerEncoded;
    _#-->                   
                            <div class="ms-srch-hover-viewerContainer ms-srch-hover-siteViewerContainer">
                                <div id="_#= idGlassViewerEncoded =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-glass-siteViewer"></div>
                                <iframe id="_#=idViewerEncoded=#_" src="_#= $urlHtmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path) =#_" scrolling="no" frameborder="0px" class="ms-srch-hover-siteViewer">
                                </iframe>                            
                            </div>
    <!--#_                                                 
                        }
    _#-->
    <div> Description: _#= line1 =#_ </div>
    <!--#_
                        var path = !Srch.U.w(ctx.CurrentItem.ParentLink) ? ctx.CurrentItem.ParentLink : ctx.CurrentItem.SiteName;
                        if(!Srch.U.w(path))
                        {                         
                            var siteResultsId = id + "_siteSearchResults";
    _#-->
                            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(siteResultsId) =#_">
                            </div>
    <!--#_
                            AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function()
                            {
                                var query = "";
                                var dataProvider = ctx.ClientControl.get_dataProvider();
                                if (dataProvider) {
                                    var states = dataProvider.get_currentQueryState()
                                    if (states) {
                                        query = states.k;
                                    }
                                }

                                Srch.SiteSearchUtil.populateSiteSearchResults(path, siteResultsId, query, id + HP.ids.noData);
                            });
                        } 
    _#-->   
                        _#= ctx.RenderBody(ctx) =#_                 
                    </div>          
                    <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.actions) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-actions">                  
                        _#= ctx.RenderFooter(ctx) =#_
                    </div>
                </div>
    <!--#_          
                if(loadSiteFrame){
                    AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function(){
                        HP.loadSiteViewer(ctx.CurrentItem.id, ctx.CurrentItem.id + HP.ids.inner, id + HP.ids.viewer, ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path, "glass_" + id + HP.ids.viewer);
                    });
                }
    _#-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have same issue here (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153615/preview-show-a-blank-box-in-search-result-page) which I never customize the display template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you hard coded loadsiteframe to false so the LoadSiteViewer is not getting called. Try debugging the JavaScript and see what happens when you change it to true.