# Preview show a blank box in search result page

Tags: search-results

I am using SP2013 on-premise standard edition. OWA is not installed in my environment. I tested search for some keyword on osssearchresults.aspx and all other search result page. It return result normally. When I mouseover the search results, a preview pop-up. However, the problem is, for all the "web page" results the preview shows a blank box instead of the preview image of that web page or site.

Notice that all the search function only search within the site collection. Hence all returned results are pages under the same site collection. When I click on the results I can open the pages succesfully.

Is it expected behaivour?

Additional information: after some investigation I found the preview panel actually a iframe browsing the page. By using F12 code I found the iframe code is like:

```
<iframe class="ms-srch-hover-siteViewer" id="ctl00_ctl46_g_04309123_4bba_486f_9acb_724dacc7d03a_csr3_item_hoverViewer" src="https://sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/xxxxx/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx" frameBorder="0px" scrolling="no">
```

The src address is working fine. I can browse it without any warning or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />` in my Master page and the preview iframe is working immediately (without re-crawl).

Related reading: http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-enable-page-previews-in.html